# mapping not showing any value corresponding to string key(converted from bytes32)

Tags: solidity, bytes, bytes32

I have bytes32 data which needs to be converted into a string, then use to get value from mapping(string => string)

Trying to convert bytes32 to string using : `string(abi.encodePacked(temp))`

It is working fine:

[image]

[image]

Mapping contains key value pair : `"har0 => "hello"`

[image: mapping]

But when I uses the same string(converting from bytes32) in mapping to get the value, it doesn't gives value.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to decode packed data, which is not possible with `abi.decode`. As `abi.decode` can only decode the data that's not packed.

The correct way to decode a bytes input is this

```
  function convert(bytes memory data) public pure returns (string memory) {
        return abi.decode(data,(string));
    }
```

And to get the mapping:

```
function getmap(bytes memory key) public view returns (string memory) {
    return map[convert(key)];
}
```

try this and it will be working.

In case you really want to work with ancodePacked, you can look into some assembly code for this.
Here is a relatable answer : [How to decode `encodePacked` data](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/143522/how-to-decode-encodepacked-data)

Comment: Please help me out !

Comment: Did you try what I told you?
It's working for me

Comment: yes, actually I have tried using with extra zeros at end like 0x68617230 rather than 0x686172300000.. 32 bytes total. It works fine. But I want to use bytes32 actually

Comment: Okay, it won't be possible because solidity doesn't have any function to decode packed data. Using assembly can solve your problem. 
Editing my answer with this update.

Comment: Updated the answer, please mark it as answer if it helped you.